# Count likes on a Facebook post using Python+Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, recommendation-engine

I want to count how many times a friend has liked a user's post using Python.

I have successfully fetched the names of friends who have liked the posts. But there are some posts which don't have any like at all. The code gives an error there. I'm using [facebook-sdk 1.0.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/facebook-sdk). Any help would be much appreciated.
Code snippet is:

```
import facebook
graph=facebook.GraphAPI(access_token="")
posts=graph.get_connections(id="me",connection_name="posts")
for w in range (0,5):
    p1=posts['data'][w]['likes']['data']
    for i in range (0,len(p1)):
      r=p1[i]['name']
      print(r)
```

Also, Is there any way to find out the list of friends hitting maximum likes on all posts?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unsure on exactly what you are missing here or what your question is, but it looks like all you need to do is define the name you want to look for and count how many times it occurs in your code.

Something like this:

```
import facebook

likes = 0 # How many times they likes on your posts 
friend = "Bob" # Your friends name   

graph=facebook.GraphAPI(access_token="")
posts=graph.get_connections(id="me",connection_name="posts")
for w in range (0,5):
    p1=posts['data'][w]['likes']['data']
    for i in range (0,len(p1)):
      if friend == p1[i]['name']
          likes += 1
print likes
```

Also, you could clean up your code considerably if you ditched the ranges for your for loops and instead iterated over the data structures themselves. Something like this would work:

```
import facebook

likes = 0 # How many times they likes on your posts 
friend = "Bob" # Your friends name   

graph=facebook.GraphAPI(access_token="")
posts=graph.get_connections(id="me",connection_name="posts")

for user_post in posts['data']:
    for name in user_post['likes']['data']:
      if friend == name['name']
          likes += 1
```

Comment: thanx .. I want to count likes on the user's post for every friend of the user and instead of giving name statically to a variable,suggest some other way so that count for each friend can be determined

Comment: Instead of checking for an individual friend, keep a dictionary with the friends name as the key. Whenever you find a name, check if it exists. If it does, increment the value by one. If the name does not exist, initialize a key with their name and a value of one. You can then print out all of the keys and values in the dictionary to get a complete breakdown of likes on posts.

Comment: i have tried to add friends name in a list but facing an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp-\Downloads\file1.py", line 33, in <module>
    if((likename[y])==(likename[x])):
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: for w in range (0,len(posts['data'])):
 try:
        p1=posts['data'][w]['likes']['data']
        for i in range (0,len(p1)):
          r=p1[i]['name']
          likename.append(r)        
    except:
        pass
l_name=len(likename)
print (l_name)
p=0
for x in range (0,l_name):
    for y in range (0,len(likename)):   
         if((likename[y])==(likename[x])):
            p +=1
            del likename[y]
         
    l_name=len(likename)
    likename_count.append(p)   
    p=0
print(len(likename))        
count=len(likename_count)
print(count)

Comment: Honestly, I am not going to try to debug your code that is unformatted in a comment. The error that you are getting is a very trivial error, try googling it. I also wouldn't recommend a list, but you can do whatever you want to do.